# How can i fix this PostgreSQL installation Error?

Tags: postgresql

`psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required.` I'm currently having problems at the moment of the installation for PostgreSQL, and i have no idea how to fix it, sorry for my bad english

I tried changing ports and passwords, but as expected, it didn't work

Comment: 1) Reading the docs is a good start [SSL config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SSL). 2) Adequate information would also be nice: a) Postgres version. b) OS and version. c) Method of Postgres installation and source of install files. 3) Lastly **do not use images** for textual information, copy and paste as text.

Comment: thank you, i will try all of it, and sorry about the image, is my first time using stack overflow

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `PGSSLMODE` to `disable` before you connect with `psql`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.